# How come I can't print this custom excel slide range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, printing, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

So, I basically wanted to print a range of slides. I have about 800 slides in one PowerPoint and I wanted to print out every other slide, so I made the following numbers separated by a comma using Microsoft Excel:

> 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,97,99,101,103,105,107,109,111,113,115,117,119,121,123,125,127,129,131,133,135,137,139,141,143,145,147,149,151,153,155,157,159,161,163,165,167,169,171,173,175,177,179,181,183,185,187,189,191,193,195,197,199,201,203,205,207,209,211,213,215,217,219,221,223,225,227,229,231,233,235,237,239,241,243,245,247,249,251,253,255,257,259,261,263,265,267,269,271,273,275,277,279,281,283,285,287,289,291,293,295,297,299,301,303,305,307,309,311,313,315,317,319,321,323,325,327,329,331,333,335,337,339,341,343,345,347,349,351,353,355,357,359,361,363,365,367,369,371,373,375,377,379,381,383,385,387,389,391,393,395,397,399,401,403,405,407,409,411,413,415,417,419,421,423,425,427,429,431,433,435,437,439,441,443,445,447,449,451,453,455,457,459,461,463,465,467,469,471,473,475,477,479,481,483,485,487,489,491,493,495,497,499,501,503,505,507,509,511,513,515,517,519,521,523,525,527,529,531,533,535,537,539,541,543,545,547,549,551,553,555,557,559,561,563,565,567,569,571,573,575,577,579,581,583,585,587,589,591,593,595,597,599,601,603,605,607,609,611,613,615,617,619,621,623,625,627,629,631,633,635,637,639,641,643,645,647,649,651,653,655,657,659,661,663,665,667,669,671,673,675,677,679,681,683,685,687,689,691,693,695,697,699,701,703,705,707,709,711,713,715,717,719,721,723,725,727,729,731,733,735,737,739,741,743,745,747,749,751,753,755,757,759,761,763,765,767,769,771,773,775,777,779,781

The problem is it will only print out if I used all the numbers up to around 167 (1 to 167), but states if I include the other larger numbers around the point, an error message states, "This isn't a valid print range." How can I get input all these numbers to print out the number of slides I want, using the "custom range:" text box?

Comment: Your post about the same problem in the PowerPoint section of Microsoft Answers has been answered there. Basically, the trick is to write a macro to hide every other slide, then print, making sure the option to choose hidden slides is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you can only use 255 characters in the custom slide range box:

[image]